# Struts Hidden field does not hold the values

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have a webpage display the list of values with the following data structure.

```
Class MyBean 
private List<NewObj> newList;
getNewList();
setNewList(List);

Class NewObj
private String name;
private List<CustObj> custList;
getCustList();
setCustList(List);

Class CustObj
private String age;
```

I am able to iterate through the list and display the values. I have included the hidden tags in between so that I can get the values in Action class back from Form.

**JSP:**

```
<s:iterator value="myBean.newList" status="matStat">
    <s:hidden name="myBean.newList[%(#matStat.index)].name"></s:hidden>
    <tr>
       <td><s:property value="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <s:iterator value="custList" status="reqStatus">
     <s:hidden name="myBean.newList[%(#matStatus.index)].custList[%(#reqStatus.index)].requestId">         </s:hidden>
     <tr>
        <td><s:property value="age" /></td>
     </tr>
   </s:iterator>
</s:iterator>
```

When I try to access the values from my action class, the value is NULL, I mean the object myBean is NULL.

**Action class:**

```
myBean.getNewList()
```

I am getting the NPE at the above line as the myBean object is empty. FYI, I have both getter and setter of myBean in the action class.

**JSP Source from Browser:** Following is the extract of content which I got from the browser by seeing the **View Page Source**

```
<input type="hidden" name="myBean.newList[%(#matStat.index)].name" value="" id="myForm_myBean_newList[%(#matStat.index)].name"/>
```

The value of name should actually be **myBean.newList[0].name**

Comment: Well the M and the V look ok.  What about the C? :)

Comment: Where did you see this kind of expression `%(` ?

Comment: What languages are you coding?

Comment: @ne1410s: I couldnt understand your question. Can you pls elaborate?

Comment: @AleksandrM/Roman C: I am using Struts2 and that's how I used to iterate the values in jsp using struts-iterator. The hidden tag <s:hidden> is used to set the values in screen, so that it would be available in the Action class. Please correct me if I am wrong. Also, point me to any sample code for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your responses.

After doing analysis on each and every word, I found out that the expression that I was using is wrong.
I used () instead of {} for accessing the list index in struts iterator. The corrected JSP is given below. Now, its working fine.

```
<s:iterator value="myBean.newList" status="matStat">
<s:hidden name="myBean.newList[%{#matStat.index}].name"></s:hidden>
<tr>
   <td><s:property value="name" /></td>
</tr>
<s:iterator value="custList" status="reqStatus">
 <s:hidden name="myBean.newList[%{#matStatus.index}].custList[%{#reqStatus.index}].requestId">         </s:hidden>
 <tr>
    <td><s:property value="age" /></td>
 </tr>
```